# Which event fires when we cancel some App by Windows Task Manager?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, events

I need to know which event fires within an WPF application if I cancel it by Windows Task Manager?

The idea is to terminate internal App. job accurately.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about the "Applications" tab or the "Processes" tab of the task manager?

Comment: Well... Both of them may cancel App. so I have to consider all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When you use the "Processes" tab there is no event, because your process is simply killed.
- When you use the "Applications" tab, a normal `WM_CLOSE` message is sent to the top level of your application. See the last answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/549a4bbb-e77b-4c5a-b724-07996774c60a) on how to detect this in a WPF application.

Comment: +1 and to add to this, not being able to "trap" the first case is actually a "[good thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx)".

Comment: Clicking the "End Task" button in Task Manager calls the [`EndTask` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633492.aspx). Don't assume it's a graceful termination. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @CodyGray: The task manager first tries a graceful termination using `WM_CLOSE`. Only if that fails it does a hard termination.

Comment: Yes, the `EndTask` function allows that; that's what the `fForce` parameter does. I wasn't necessarily disputing your answer. The point is that it will eventually force things, which means that there's very little you can do to stop it.

Comment: @CodyGray: That's right, but nobody asked about stopping anything. He asked about the events that are fired. So, if terminating his internal application job doesn't take much time, listening to this event will work. Having said that, I agree with your answer that you can't handle all possible cases. You never can be sure, that any job correctly finishes, there is always the possibility of killing the process or a power outage...

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is to terminate internal App. job accurately.

You can't do this reliably. If the user is ending the application that way, something has either gone badly wrong or they simply don't care. There's nothing you can do, you're toast. Don't worry about cleaning up after yourself: the operating system will do that for you, no thank you required.

The best thing that you can do is handle the standard close events. Those will get triggered if the user requests to end your app in a polite way, either via the normal means or through Task Manager (Task Manager will try to ask nicely first if the user clicks "End Task" from the "Applications" tab). But since I assume you're already doing that, you've done all that you can.

Answer (score 1):

Handling the event from Task Manager is not possible as the way it works for ungracefull shut downs of applications.

However, you can try to handle the Application class' SessionEnding event which is described in MSDN at below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending.aspx